# WebRTC Data Channel Alternatives/Embedding in Android

Tags: android, mobile, webrtc

Are there any alternative technologies that will allow the opening of a "data channel" between peers? I'm looking specifically to extend this idea to a mobile app, but I can't find anything comparable.

Alternatively, is there any way to embed a data channel in a native Android app?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use webRTC data channel for P2P file sharing. As an alternative, I found BitTorrent Sync API very amazing. May be you can take a look too. There are many ideas that can possible be accomplished with BitTorrent Sync API. You can request for an API access key from here, https://www.getsync.com/api
. Also, sometimes I use webRTC data channel for P2P messaging. In this case, I recently came to know about https://github.com/ricochet-im/ricochet. May be you will find it interesting too.

Comment: Did you have any trouble with firewalls using webRTC?

Comment: No, I didn't face much trouble. In webRTC for NAT/Firewall traversal, I have multiple turn servers which is very easy to set up. I used, [rfc5766-turn-server](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/) gateway. When you search in google, you will find many other free+paid turn server.